# dereferencing pointer to incomplete type

Tags: c

i'm trying to implement tree structure in c:

this part is from the header file:

```
typedef struct SP_Tree_Node
{
    char * value;
    struct Node * children;
    int indexOfLastChild;
} Node;

typedef struct SP_Tree
{
    Node root;
} Tree;
```

when i'm trying to insert new Node into children array the next error appears:  "dereferencing pointer to incomplete type"
this is the code: (tree's type is Tree *)

```
Node * newNode = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node*));
tree->root.children[tree->root.indexOfLastChild] = newNode;
```

what am i doing wrong?
thank you!!

Comment: They say [you shouldn't cast the result of `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: `struct Node` and `Node` are unrelated until you say `typedef struct Node Node;`.

Comment: `struct Node * children;` -- there is no `struct Node` defined. It should be `struct SP_Tree_Node * children`. And you should `malloc(sizeof(Node))`.

Comment: @axiac you cannot use `Node * children;` because `Node` isn't defined there yet.

Comment: @n.m.: That will not work. He needs `struct SP_Tree_Node`. `Node` is in a different namespace. And he **does** typedef `Node`

Comment: @MikeCAT I deleted that part from my comment. I didn't program in C in the last 6 years and some of the memories started to fade out. Thank you.

Comment: `Node * newNode = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node*));` doesn't seem good. I think it should be `Node * newNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));` (allocate sizeof `Node` (the struct) instead of `Node*` (a pointer))

Comment: @Olaf `typedef struct Node Node;` workls jolly well. Unless `typedef somethingelse Node;` already exists in the same scope, which is probably a mistake and should be removed or renamed in order to keep simple things simple.

Comment: @n.m.: See the text. He already does `typedef` `Node`. He just has to use `SP_Tree_Node` instead of `Node` for `children`. There is no `struct Node` Whether one uses the same ident for the struct-tag depends on the coding standard used. I generally recommend a constant suffix or prefix. But that is a personal preference.

Comment: @Olaf no, he needs to (expletive removed) ditch the SP_Tree_Node identifier and just define `struct Node` instead. Simple. Tells the story. The tag already has the constant prefix, it's spelled `struct`.

Comment: @n.m.: That is a matter of personal preference! Leave that to each implementor. Many coding standards require to use a disctint name, e.g. with a suffix like `_s` or so to differentiate the names.

Comment: Obviously such a coding standard is not in effect here ;) If a coding standard requires you to add _s or whatever, add it, but IMO it's just noise. You already know it's an "_s", you have this nice coloured word `struct` right before it!

Answer (score 3):

`struct Node` is different from `Node`, and it doesn't seem you defined `struct Node.

Try changing `struct Node * children;` in the declaration of `struct SP_Tree_Node` to `struct SP_Tree_Node * children;`

**UPDATE:**

You use array of `Node*`, so the declaration should be `struct SP_Tree_Node ** children;` (add one more asterisk).

Comment: @this An pointer to `Node` is assigned to an element of `tree->root.children` in the code in the question, so `tree->root.children` should be (a pointer pointing at the first element of) an array of `Node*`.